# Microk8s ingress does not redirect to pod

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I'm trying to setup kubernetes for the first time, probably it's something stupid. So I have an Ubuntu server with microk8s recently installed, and I'm trying to setup a deployment for an app with nginx. I've managed to successfully start said deployment, I can connect to it directly from server's ssh. There's also an ingress controller in different from app's namespace. When I'm trying to connect via browser I get 503. There are logs of my attempts in ingress, but not in webapp.

My configs:

```
---
# Source: yii/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myapp-yii
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: yii-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
---
# Source: yii/templates/host-config.yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend-host-config
data:
  default.conf: |
    server {
      client_max_body_size 10m;

      root /var/www/web;

      location /health {
        return 200;
      }

      location / {
          # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
          try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
      }

      location ~* ^.+\\.(css|js)$ {
          access_log off;
          log_not_found off;
          expires max;
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin \"*\";
      }

      location ~* ^.+\\.(svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ttc|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
          access_log off;
          expires max;
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin \"*\";
      }

      location ~ ^/index\\.php(/|$) {
          fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\\.php)(/.*)$;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
          fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
          http2_push_preload on;
          proxy_buffer_size          2048k;
          proxy_buffers              4 2048k;
          proxy_busy_buffers_size    4096k;
          fastcgi_buffers            16 256k;
          fastcgi_buffer_size        512k;
          internal;
      }

      location ~ \\.php$ {
          return 404;
      }
    }
---
# Source: yii/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-yii
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: yii-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 9000
      name: fastcgi
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
---
# Source: yii/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-yii
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: yii-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-token
      serviceAccountName: myapp-yii
      securityContext:
        {}
      volumes:
        - name: vendor-dir
          emptyDir: { }
        - name: upload-dir
          emptyDir: { }
        - name: runtime-dir
          emptyDir: { }
        - name: assets-dir
          emptyDir: { }
        - name: host-config
          configMap:
            name: backend-host-config
      initContainers:
        - name: app-dependencies
          image: "[app-image]"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'composer install --no-interaction --classmap-authoritative']
          envFrom: &envFrom
            - secretRef:
                name: backend-env
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/vendor
              name: vendor-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/web/upload
              name: upload-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/runtime
              name: runtime-dir
        - name: app-migrations
          image: "[app-image]"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          envFrom: *envFrom
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/vendor
              name: vendor-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/web/upload
              name: upload-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/runtime
              name: runtime-dir
          command: [ 'sh', '-c', './yii migrate --interactive=0' ]
        - name: app-cache-clear
          image: "[app-image]"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          envFrom: *envFrom
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/vendor
              name: vendor-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/web/upload
              name: upload-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/runtime
              name: runtime-dir
          command: [ 'sh', '-c', './yii cache/flush-all --interactive=0' ]
      containers:
        - name: app
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "[app-image]"
          envFrom: *envFrom
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/vendor
              name: vendor-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/web/upload
              name: upload-dir
            - mountPath: /var/www/runtime
              name: runtime-dir
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: http
          resources:
            {}
        - name: webapp
          image: "[webapp-image]"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
              name: host-config
---
# Source: yii/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-yii
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: yii-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: cert-issuer-staging
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: cert-issuer-staging
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: http
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 1M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: index.php
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: default/fastcgi-config
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/http2-push-preload: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "myapp.site"
      secretName: myapp-tls
  rules:
    - host: "myapp.site"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-yii
                port:
                  name: http
---
# Source: yii/templates/issuer.yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: cert-issuer-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: "[email]"
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: myapp-tls
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
---
# Source: yii/templates/tests/test-connection.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "myapp-yii-test-connection"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: yii-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: yii
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: wget
      image: busybox
      command: ['wget']
      args: ['myapp-yii:80/health']
  restartPolicy: Never
```

When trying to access via browser this appears in ingress logs:

```
<client-ip> - - [28/Oct/2023:11:52:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 592 "-" <client-useragent> [myapp-myapp-yii-http] [] - - - - cbf11499bb04aa4c4cc2fdff838a6ff4
```

`kubectl get service myapp-yii -n myapp`

```
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
myapp-yii     ClusterIP   10.152.183.239   <none>        80/TCP,9000/TCP   22h
```

`kubectl get ingress -n myapp`

```
NAMESPACE   NAME          CLASS   HOSTS          ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
myapp       myapp-yii     nginx   myapp.site     127.0.0.1   80, 443   13h
```

`kubectl get deployment -n myapp`

```
NAME          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
myapp-yii     1/1     1            1           22h
```

`kubectl get pod -n myapp`

```
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
myapp-yii-775597f9d8-p76rf     2/2     Running   0          13h
```

I don't know if external-ip being `<none>` and/or ingress address `127.0.0.1` affects the issue, but I could not resolve both problems.

Edit: to minimize the human factor, we switched to helm. Also tried exposing pod outside by adding

```
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - [server-ip]
```

this way we were able to access webapp via browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Ingress' annotations ruins our case, we only left two: issuer and ingress.class, and now it all works fine